# Set Maximum SearchCriteria pageSize to 500

Tags: magento2, api, webapi

How set Maximum SearchCriteria pageSize to 500.

In documentation Magento is present this page but not found these options

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/services/magento-web-api.html

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a custom module: Create a custom module if you don't already have one. You can follow this guide to create a basic module in Magento 2.

2.Create di.xml file: In your custom module, create a di.xml file at app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml.

3.Define the plugin: In your di.xml file, define the plugin for the Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder class by adding the following code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder">
        <plugin name="[Vendor]_[Module]::setMaxPageSize" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\SearchCriteriaBuilder" />
    </type>
</config>
```

4.Create the plugin class: In your module, create the SearchCriteriaBuilder.php file at app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/SearchCriteriaBuilder.php. Add the following code to the class to set the maximum page size to 500:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class SearchCriteriaBuilder
{
    /**
     * Set the maximum page size to 500
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $subject
     * @param int $pageSize
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function beforeSetPageSize(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $subject,
        $pageSize
    ) {
        if ($pageSize > 500) {
            $pageSize = 500;
        }

        return [$pageSize];
    }
}
```

This code sets the maximum page size to 500 by overriding the setPageSize method in the SearchCriteriaBuilder class.